# Determine existence of results in jet SQL?

Tags: sql, jet, exists, iif

In Jet, I want to test if certain conditions return any results.

I want a query which returns exactly one record: "true" if there are any results, "false" otherwise.

This works in MS SQL:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM foo WHERE <some condition>)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
  END;
```

This is what I have tried in Jet:

```
SELECT IIF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM foo WHERE <some condition>), 0, 1);
```

which gives me the error:

```
Reserved error (-3025); there is no message for this error.
```

Any ideas?

**NOTE**
I don't want to select "true" multiple times by tacking on a FROM clause at the end, because it could be slow (if the FROM table had many records) or undefined (if the table had 0 records).

Comment: Usually that would be correllated - the example would always return 0 if the table existed in the database.

Comment: @OMG_Ponies edited my example and tried it. Still doesn't work.

Comment: What if you add SELECT IIF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM foo WHERE <some condition>), 0, 1) FROM <some table>;

Comment: @Phaedrus Thanks! It almost worked. Unfortunately, it selects "1" for each entry in the from-clause table, and one of the reasons for doing it this way is so that I can get one and only one result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
SELECT TOP 1 IIF(EXISTS(
       SELECT * FROM foo 
       WHERE <some condition>), 0, 1) As f1 
FROM foo
```

Perhaps more clearly:

```
SELECT TOP 1 IIF(EXISTS(
       SELECT * FROM foo
       WHERE <some condition>), 0, 1) As F1 
FROM MSysObjects
```

Comment: By adding the from clause, I end up selecting the result of the test, but I get as many records as there are in foo. I would only like to get one record.

Comment: @Remou not with an iif immediately following, and who knows what would happen if the FROM table for some reason had no records.

Comment: You can use any table or query that has records to select the top 1 from, above is an example using a system table from Access.

Comment: I don't see any problem at all with the TOP 1 IIf(). I've just tested Remou's SQL in Access and it works just fine. You haven't identified where you're running this SQL -- perhaps it's from outside Access and that's the problem? If so, you might move the TOP 1 from the SELECT to the FROM by using "FROM (SELECT TOP 1 MSysObjects)".

Comment: + 1: using TOP 1 is much faster than DISTINCT... though DISTINCT only takes about 300 ms on my machine using a 100K row table ;)

Comment: Yah, you're right, TOP 1 works, though it still requires a FROM clause. I guess that will have to be my compromise. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to use a count

```
SELECT DISTINCT IIF((SELECT COUNT(*) AS Result FROM [Data Set]), 1, 0) FROM [Data Set];
```

Comment: Thanks! That's almost what I want to do, except (though I don't know the inner workings of Jet that well) I suspect that DISTINCT needs to look at each record. I just want to get the result of the EXISTS clause, which would be nice and fast, always.

Comment: (and for that matter, COUNT needs to look at each record.)

Comment: @des4maisons - Just a thought, but could you create a Dummy Table with 1 record in it and in the *last* FROM clause instead of [Data Set] you would put [Dummy Table]?  That would probably eliminate the DISTINCT.

Comment: @des4maisons - Use EXISTS or use COUNT, what ever suits your needs.  I didn't know that Jet SQL supported EXISTS.

Comment: @roygbiv yah that would work ... unfortunately this software is to be run on our clients' databases, and we don't want to add to their databases without a really good reason.

Comment: @roygbiv not with an iif statement right afterwards. Also, if the FROM  table happened to have no results, who knows what the behaviour would be.

Answer (score 0):

Most EXISTS queries can be re-written as a left join:

```
    SELECT
      CASE
        WHEN foo.col is NULL 
        THEN 0
        ELSE 1
    END;
   ... LEFT JOIN foo on <where condition>
```

Comment: I want to get one and only one result no matter what records are there... or aren't. This is why left joins won't work for me. I could use count, but I don't want it to have to look at each record it pulls up before deciding there are more than 0 records.